# Can it be efficient to move by changing the center of mass?

Tags: mass, centrifugal-force

(Note, I'm not a physics expert.)

Imagine an elongated (oblong) device with some liquid inside. This device can change its center of mass by changing the distribution of the liquid. Let's say, the liquid can be in one of two polar opposite places of the device.

[image]

Now imagine this device being weightless in a free fall and rotating around its center of mass with certain periodicity of `R` rpm.

I feel like it is possible to move the device by cleverly changing its center of mass with certain periodicity `F` related to `R` (e.g., `F = n * R`). Is it? Can such movement be more or less fuel-efficient in practice?

Comment: Would be better if you could add a couple picture. Its pretty difficult to understand what you mean by "elongated device with some liquid inside"

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: I imagine the classic example of a figure skater spinning and adjusting their body while maintaining their centre of mass - then, due to conservation of angular momentum, their rotation speed changes. To change the centre of mass, you could imagine giving a push, and that can certainly be periodic. Is the goal to keep the skater (or object) rotating with period $R$ after the COM has moved?

Comment: Yes, to keep it moving in the same direction with the same speed using the same cycle of moving COM

Comment: Ah, right, conservation of momentum, didn't think about it. So, if COM moves further from the center of rotation, the rotation shows down, right?

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine. yes it does slow down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your entire device doesn't make too much sense.

When the capsule is freely falling and it rotates, yes. the centrifugal force acting on the liquid will push it in a direction but you have to do some work on it to stop that rotation or it is going to rotate more than $180^\circ$ and the centrifugal force will act on the direction opposite to the initial direction and will start slowing down the capsule.

Or as you said, we could play with the COM of the fluid to achieve the motion that we need but the efficiency would be pathetic.

We need a very heavy fluid such as mercury because we don't want the device to be insanely large. Now we need a device to move the liquid and the viscous forces would dissipate energy.

We also have to consider the perpendicular axis where the device would be oscillating back and forth which is also wasting energy.

This thing in general would be very very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no external forces, then the center of mass moves with constant velocity; in particular, if it starts out stationary then it can't move. This is a standard theorem in mechanics. So if your device is in empty space, it can't change the position of its center of mass: all it can do is move itself around it.